# gammu no configuration found

Tags: php, windows, command, gammu

I have problem in using gammu in windows. First install I success, but when I reinstall gammu I cannot read config file except declare the gammurc path at command :

```
gammu -c Mypath\gammurc identify
```

but I cannot do this :

```
gammu identify
```

it will show message:

```
Warning: No configuration file found!
Warning: No configuration read, using builtin defaults!
Error opening device, it doesn't exist.
```

do you know how to fix this in windows??

Comment: Still cannot find the solution so that the gammu can read config file automatically. But I had what I want by declare the full path of file config in each command I needed, It also work for gammu-smsd for running service.

Answer (score 1):

put gammurc on this folder (replace username with the windows username)
C:\Users \ username \ AppData\Roaming

and that is an example file content

```
[gammu]
port= com12:
connection = at115200
```

---

im use this configuration file on nokia cs-18 3g/gsm modem

Answer (score 0):

You should put **gammurc** in bin directory.